# How to create a MonadRandom (StateT PureMT m0)? (Haskell)

Tags: haskell, monads, monad-transformers, state-monad

I am trying to use `MonadRandom` from https://hackage.haskell.org/package/random-fu-0.2.6.0/docs/Data-Random.html#g:6

Specifically, I have a function with the type signature:

`randomN :: MonadRandom m => m Int`

and I want to run it using the Mersenne Twister with a known seed.

How to I "create" an instance of 
`Monad m0 => MonadRandom (StateT PureMT m0)` from the documentation?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Since the instance for `MonadRandom` is already there for `Monad m => StateT PureMT m`, you just need something like

```
-- State s a = StateT s Identity a
test :: State PureMT (Int, Int)
test = do
    a <- randomN
    b <- randomN
    return (a, b)
```

And you can run it as

```
main :: IO ()
main = do
    -- You can replace 1234 with whatever seed you want
    let (result, finalState) = runState test $ pureMT 1234
    putStr "The result: "
    print result
    putStr "The final state: "
    print finalState
```

Answer (score 0):

Ok, I've figured out how to solve my problem.

Since the documentation for `MonadRandom` asserts that a `StateT PureMT m0` can be considered to be a MonadRandom, we can "pretend" that `randomN` actually returns a `StateT PureMT m0`. We will choose `m0` to be the identity monad, in other words, we can act as if `randomN` has the signature

`randomN :: StateT PureMT Identity Int`

Now to get back the value we simply unwrap:
`runIdentity (evalStateT (randomN) $ pureMT seed)`

Comment: We aren't actually "pretending" that `randomN` returns a `StateT PureMT m0 Int`, because it actually is _in that context_.  That would be like saying that we have to pretend that `f :: Num a => a -> a`; `f x = x + 1` returns an `Int` when calling `f (1 :: Int)`.  The typeclass gets "concreted" when given a specific type to work with.